# Adding users to spring 3 security

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-3

I'm thinking about implementing authorization of the users via spring 3 security. I know that usernames and passwords are being stored in some XML file like this:

```xml
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
       <user name="username" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

But I wonder, how to add users or change password? Can anybody show me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Luke. Storing username and passwords in XML is not a good practice. Store user details in a database so you can add modify them.

***Create database***

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
     username VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
     password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
     enabled BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (username)  
);  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS authorities (  
     username VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
     authority VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
     FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users(username)
); 

insert into users(username,password,enabled) values ('abc','123456',TRUE);   
insert into authorities(username,AUTHORITY) values ('abc', 'ROLE_USER');
```

here table names, column names are used according to Spring Security default query( 'select username, password, enabled from users where username = ?' ). Because when we use default names we do not need to explicitly specify query to fetch user details. Check [Spring Security documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html) for more details.

***DataSource***

You need to have a datasource bean defined as follows because spring security need to connect database to get user details and so you need to tell it which driver, database URL, username and password. for example as follows.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/elab" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

***Spring security configuration***

Now we need to tell spring security to user database to get login details. So instead of user-service which is a inmemory UserDetailsService we use ['jdbc-user-service'](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-jdbc-user-service). Now our authentication manager will look like following.

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Note that if user table structure is different from how Spring expect in default you should explicitly specify the query as a property(users-by-username-query) for jdbc-user-service element. For more information please refer to the documentation.

Now all set and Spring will happily fetch user details from database.

Answer (score 2):

The `user-service` element creates an [`InMemoryUserDetailsManager`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/provisioning/InMemoryUserDetailsManager.java) which has methods for modifying users and changing password.

However, defining users in XML is really only intended for testing. If you want to be able to add and update user information, then you should use a database. The standard Spring Security database schema are documented in the [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#appendix-schema).

You can then either use the [JDBC `UserDetailsManager` implementation](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.java) or you can build your own custom data management code.